# Solving Unicode with Rails 2.3.9? Convert a simple string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, encoding, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using the Twitter API with the official ruby gem wrapper.

When I do Twitter::Search.new("keywords"). It returns a hash with a text field that look likes this:

text: "Merci @Isabouriaud @nicod92160 @NicolasAtger Watson "une des r\u00E9alisations"

I know this is unicode but couldn't find a way to convert this string in plain text in ruby. It has nothing to do with my database since I'm showing the tweets right away...

I just need the function to convert "r\u00E9alisations" in "réalisations"

I tried:
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("\"\u00E9\"") => é
but
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("\"\invit\u00E9\"") != invité (how I want it)

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.
[image]

**Solution**

I had to use the latest json gem and parse it with it. The current twitter gem for rails 2.3 is probably not up-to-date anymore.

I think an other solution would be to upgrade to Rails 3 and use the force_encoding method.

```
class TwitterWrapper


  def self.base
    "http://search.twitter.com"
  end


  #json_string.gsub!(/\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/) {|s| [$1.to_i(16)].pack("U")}
  def self.search(keyword)
    keyword = keyword.gsub(" ","%20")
    read("#{base}/search.json?q=#{keyword}")["results"]
  end

  private

  def self.read(url)
    JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url)))
  end

end
```

Comment: It's pretty weird that most characters are escaped, but some (あ, す, で) are not... :-/

Comment: Yeah and that's the direct output of http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=keyword - I spent 2 hours trying to figure out the solution..

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the prepresentation of the unicode string in the ruby terminal. If you write it to a file and open it with some editor with unicode support, the accent should look fine.

You can set $KCODE = 'UTF-8' to fix this for the terminal.

Comment: Thanks Mosch for your answer. But it was also showing it like that in my web browser even though I had everything encoded in UTF-8. I found a solution, will edit my post.